# why my code does not get connected with the given url

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String  myUrl="http://www.google.com.bd/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String result;
    try {
        result = doHttpUrlConnectionAction(myUrl);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


private String doHttpUrlConnectionAction(String desiredUrl) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    URL url=null;
    String result;
    try {
        url=new URL(desiredUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)    url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
        connection.connect();
        result="connected";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        result="disconnected";
    }
    return result;
}

}
```

I think this code will connect with the given url but this code always shows disconnect message.I use `ACCESS_NETWORKS_STATE` and INTERNET permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Please help me. I want to use this code in my university project.

Comment: Give your stacktrace from `e` object of Exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is asked multiple no. of times before also

but add this to your androidmanifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and use AsyncTask() class for network operations. and if you want to do operation on main thread use this line of code before operation

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = 
        new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Async task for interacting with http connection.